# Determining points where $f$ is differentiable

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $z\in\mathbb{C}$ and $f(z)=z(2-Re z)(1+Imz)$. Find the derivative of $f$ at points where $f$ is differentiable. I have determined the following: $u(x,y)=Ref(z), v(x,y)=Imf(z)$
$$
  \begin{cases}u_x = 2 -2x +2y - 2xy\\v_y=2-x+4y-2xy\end{cases}\Rightarrow -2x + 2y     = -x  +4y\Leftrightarrow x = -2y $$
and
$$\begin{cases}u_y = 2x -x^2\\-v_x = y + y^2\end{cases}\Rightarrow 2x - x^2 = y+y^2\Rightarrow 2(-2y) - (-2y)^2 = y+y^2\Leftrightarrow y^2+y=0$$
Because $u_x,u_y,v_x,v_y\in\mathbb{R}[X,Y]$, they are continous in $\mathbb{R}^2$ which means $u,v$ are differentiable in $\mathbb{R}^2$. By Cauchy-Riemann equations we conclude $f$ is differentiable at $z_1:=0, z_2:=2-i$, but here I lose all steering, let $h=r(\cos\varphi+i\sin\varphi)$:
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(z_1+h)-f(z_1)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)}{h}=\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{r(\cos\varphi+i\sin\varphi)(2-r\cos\varphi)(1+r\sin\varphi)}{r} = 2(\cos\varphi+i\sin\varphi)$$
Did we not conclude that $f$ is differentiable at $0$, i.e it has a derivative? How come it depends on $\varphi$? What have I done wrong?

EDIT: Nothing's wrong, let's divide by the whole $h$ then $f'(z_1)= 2$, we have steering again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your derivative, you divided by $r$, not the whole $h$.

Comment: Oh god, such an obvious mistake. Mechanical thinking will be the end of me